# $scope not being acessed in the view

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Angular in an application. After getting a specific object (a movie in my case), I'm assigning the object to `$scope` (`$scope.movie = response`), so that I can use it in the view. The problem is that my view seems not to display anything I use in `$scope`. I've tried deleting everything and doing a dummy test like `$scope=name="whatever"` and when I use something like `{{name}}` in the view nothing is rendered. Have anyone faced this problem ? I've already searched for this error, and it seems like it would be a good idea to use `$apply()`. I've tried that and it didn't work. The function that fetches the data is below:

```
var app = angular.module('movies');

app.factory('Films', ['$resource',function($resource){
 return $resource('/films.json', {},{
 query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
 create: { method: 'POST' }
 })
}]);

app.factory('Film', ['$resource', function($resource){
 return $resource('films/:id.json', {}, {
 show: {method: 'GET' },
 update: { method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@id'} },
 delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'} }
 });
}]);

app.controller('MoviesController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$resource', '$routeParams', 'Films', 'Film', function($scope, $http, $location, $resource, $routeParams, Films, Film){

  $scope.movies = Films.query();

  $scope.user = document.getElementById('name').innerHTML; // Find a better way to interact with devise via angular

  $scope.createMovie = function() {
    $scope.movies = Films.query();

    $http.get(
      '/categories.json'
    ).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
      $scope.categories = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
      alert("There was an error while fetching the categories on the database. Error " + status);
    });

    $location.path("/" + 'new').replace();
  };

  $scope.listMovies = function() {
    $location.path("/").replace();
  };

  $scope.save = function(){
    if($scope.form.$valid){
        Films.create({film: $scope.movie}, function(){
        $scope.form.$setPristine();
      }, function(error){
        alert("Movie not created");
      });
    }
  };

  $scope.deleteMovie = function(movie){
    Film.delete(movie);
    $scope.movies = Films.query();
  };

  $scope.viewDetails = function(movie){
    $scope.name="ola";
    alert(movie.id);
    $location.path("/" + movie.id);
    var Movie = $resource('films/:filmId'+'.json', {filmId: '@id'});
    $scope.movie = Movie.get({filmId: movie.id});
    $scope.movie.$promise.then(
      function(response){
        $scope.$apply();
        $scope.movie = response;

        console.log("filme e: " + response.name);
      },
      function(error){
        console.log("request failed");
      }
    );
  };

}]);
```

Comment: Can you paste the rest of your controller and your view code?

Comment: Paste some view's code please.

Comment: I understand the `$scope.name="ola"` is your dummy code but it won't be attached to the `$scope` and therefore displayed until you click `viewDetails()`.

Comment: The view is here:  https://github.com/mcand/angularrails/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/templates/movie_details.html

Comment: Yeah. When i click to see the details of a movie, then the function viewDetails in MovieController is called. It searches the movie with the given id in the routeParams and then update the $scope to be shown in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at your repository and I think where your problem is. You are trying to reuse the `MoviesController` in all of your routes. But AngularJS will create a new instance for every route and therefore you can't access your previous data because it will be destroyed.

So I would start by creating a separated controller for each view, so you can move the code of your `viewDetails` method to a new `MovieDetailController`. To have access to the movie id in this controller, you need to use the `$routeParams` service.

```
angular.module('movies').controller('MovieDetailController', MovieDetailController);

function MovieDetailController($scope, $resource, $routeParams) {
  var Movie = $resource('films/:filmId'+'.json', {filmId: '@id'});
  Movie.get({filmId: $routeParams.id}).then(
    function(response) {
      $scope.movie = response;
    }, 
    function(error){
      console.log('request failed');
    }
  );
}
```

Change your route definition to use the new controller.

```
.when('/movies/:id', {
  controller: 'MovieDetailController',
  templateUrl: 'movie_details.html'
})
```

And now your `viewDetails` method in the `MoviesController` just need to redirect to the movie detail url.

```
$scope.viewDetails = function(movie) {
  $location.path('/movies/' + movie.id); 
}
```

I hope it works for you. Let me know when you try!

Comment: If I put something like {{parent().movies}} in that details view I get all the movies as an array. OK. If It's creating another instance of this controller (MovieController), is this controller a child of the same controller (MovieController) ? Because that seems the case.

Comment: $parent.movies, not parent().movies. Sorry.

Comment: I've tried creating another controller, but it didn't work. Even though in the view the MovieDetailController is "nested" within MovieController.

Comment: It shouldn't be nested. I've updated the route definition to `/movies/:id` so you can try cause maybe the router is messing up.

Comment: I've solved the problem. It was related to the controller as you have said. Thank you very much! I should use a new controller for every new view in Angular, then ? When I was designing the code, I thought that every action should be in the same controller just as Rails framework do.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with reusing controllers but having one per view will make the code cleaner and the controller thinner. As you are just starting with AngularJS have a look at the [controller as](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) syntax so you can get rid of the `$scope` object.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. AngularJS inspector has helped me to understand how scope works too. It even shows dependencies in my controller I was not using and name conventions. :)